# MediaPlayer Android programming google text to speech.

Tags: android, json, text-to-speech

Don't get the wrong sound when playing, when I enter text in English then I'll get everything and the result gives sootvetstvuyushaya word,

but when I change the url to: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ru&q=привет and open computer browser then I'm fine but when I enter the url in the source code that gives me no intelligible speech, give that to me to do

**This is my code:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

try {           
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    player.setDataSource("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ru&q=привет");
    player.prepare();
    player.start();

} catch (Exception e) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "speaking error!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

}

Comment: can you see my asnwer below,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread x;
MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer;
 x=new Thread(){    
public void run(){
         try{
             url1="http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q="this is word which is speech"%0A&tl="this is language"&prev=input";


            mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url1);
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            mediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    } 


            finally{ 
            //  x.suspend();
            } 
     }

    };
```

then you can call like this :

```
x.start();
```